# Rails Parse Active record validation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following in my controller:

```
def create
    equipment = Equipment.create(:name => params[:name])
    errors = equipment.errors.messages
    puts "equipment errors: " + errors.inspect
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @equipment }
    end
end
```

The response from the 'puts' is:

```
equipment errors: {:name=>["has already been taken"]}
```

How do I parse the error and get the message?

Thanks

Comment: also- your line `format.json {render :json => @equipment}` won't work unless you make `equipment = Equipment.create` -> `@equipment = Equipment.create`    you are making it local, but referencing an instance variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
equipment.errors.full_messages.join(", ")
```

This should give you "Name has already been taken". It concatenates all the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Its just a hash.  Access the message with

`errors[:name].first`

This gets the value of the `:name` key from the hash, which is an array with one element, and then returns the value of the first element of the array, which is the error message.

With more errors, use [Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html) functions to access all of them and display them appropriately.